# Facebook-javascript-sdk sometimes giving OAuthException#2500 (An active access token must be used to query information about the current user)

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

```js
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '154776817xxxxxxx',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.1'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

   function checkLoginState(chackStatus) {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      if (response.status === 'connected') {
        FB.api('/me?fields=id,name,birthday,email,first_name,gender,hometown,last_name,location,middle_name,picture', function(response) {
           console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
         });
      } else {
         FB.login( function(){
           FB.api('/me?fields=id,name,birthday,email,first_name,gender,hometown,last_name,location,middle_name,picture', function(response) {
           console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
         });
        },{scope: 'email,user_birthday'});
       }
    });
  }
```

Facebook Response  :

{
        "error" : {
            "message" : "**An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.**",
            "type" : "OAuthException",
            "code" : NumberLong(2500),
            "fbtrace_id" : "D3axJ2QxG1h"
        },
        "image" : "https://graph.facebook.com//picture?type=large"
}

Comment: see my answer. for a better analysis, please add more details. for example, were EXACTLY does that error happen?

Answer (score 0):

The question is: When exactly do you call `checkLoginState`? You must call it after F`B.init`, after the JS SDK is loaded. That being said, there is an issue with `FB.login`, you are calling it in the asynchronous callback of `FB.getLoginStatus` - you MUST call it on user interaction instead, or browsers will block the popup. In general, use `FB.getLoginStatus` right after FB.init and `FB.login` on user interaction (mouse click).

Also, make sure the user is authorized in the callback of `FB.login`.

For example: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/